# Can I force Xcode to call its windows in Mission Controller by project and not by file?

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina

When I go into mission control on mac, I can see the various Xcode windows I have open on a given desktop.

When you hover over the windows with cursor, the windows are called by the current tab / file that you are in i.e: `MainController.swift`, `RefreshViewModel.swift` etc.

Is there a way to make macOS / Xcode behave in such a way that these windows by the project / workspace that you opened? So instead of `MainController.swift` I would see `ProjectA.xcproject` or `ProjectB.xcworkspace`. I guess not, but I would like to know if there are any options to help my workflow.